# forEach@ error with Karma

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When I use module and try and inject a controller in karma, I get this error

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Tests for Profile Controller should work FAILED
        forEach@/Users/work/Sites/APP/web-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:24
        loadModules@/Users/work/Sites/APP/web-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4548:12
        createInjector@/Users/work/Sites/APP/web-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4470:30
        workFn@/Users/work/Sites/APP/web-app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2954:60
        /Users/work/Sites/APP/web-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4588:53
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.016 secs)
```

my test

```
describe('Tests for Profile Controller', function(){

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  var scope, $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

  it('should work', function(){

    expect('defined').toBeDefined();
  })
})
```

My Karma config looks like this

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [

      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'dist/js/combined.bower.js',
      'app/js/routes.js',
      'app/js/controllers/profile.js',
      'app/test/unit/controllers/profile.spec.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    singleRun: false,

    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

My apps module is defined inside my routes.js (not my idea) and the controller im trying to test right now is profile.controller. My bower.combined is all of my bower components concatenated and minified. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you figure out a fix?

Comment: Turns out it were issues with how things were being loaded in my karma conf. I resolved the issue by first loading a combined bower file, then angular mocks (for some reason being in the combined bower isnt enough, followed by my angular module ( i had to separate the declaration out of my routes file, then my controllers folder, then my test folder. Best advice I can give that helped me tremendously would be to isolate your test to one simple controller. Copy its contents to another file and just load in scope. get a test to work. Then slowly re add dependencies to see what breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it were issues with how things were being loaded in my karma conf. I resolved the issue by first loading a combined bower file, then angular mocks (for some reason being in the combined bower isnt enough, followed by my angular module ( i had to separate the declaration out of my routes file, then my controllers folder, then my test folder. Best advice I can give that helped me tremendously would be to isolate your test to one simple controller. Copy its contents to another file and just load in scope. get a test to work. Then slowly re add dependencies to see what breaks